# How to properly set timespec for sem_timedwait to protect against EINVAL error

Tags: c, semaphore, time.h

I'm trying to use sem_timedwait() to repeatedly lock and unlock a semaphore. Based on the example [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_timedwait.html), I was setting my struct timespec in the following way for a 20 msec timeout:

```
sem_t semaphore;  //initialized somewhere else

void waitForSomething ()
{
    int ret;
    struct timespec ts;

    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts) == -1)
    {
        //throw error
    }
    ts.tv_nsec += 20000000; //timeout of 20 msec 

    while ((ret = sem_timedwait(&semaphore, &ts)) == -1 && errno == EINTR)
        continue;

    if (ret == -1 && errno != ETIMEDOUT) {
        //flag error
    } else {
        //do something
    }

    return;
}
```

With the above code, my program would consistently fail after running for some time with the EINVAL error code. After debugging I realized that the failure was coming from the fact that ts.tv_nsec exceeds 1000000000 after some time. My current workaround is the following:

```
sem_t semaphore;  //initialized somewhere else

void waitForSomething ()
{
    int ret;
    struct timespec ts;

    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts) == -1)
    {
        //throw error
    }
    if (ts.tv_nsec > 979999999) {
        ts.tv_sec += 60;
        ts.tv_nsec = (ts.tv_nsec + 20000000) % 1000000000;
    } else {
        ts.tv_nsec += 20000000; 
    }

    while ((ret = sem_timedwait(&semaphore, &ts)) == -1 && errno == EINTR)
        continue;

    if (ret == -1 && errno != ETIMEDOUT) {
        //throw error
    } else {
        // do something
    }
    return;
}
```

I'm wondering - is there a better way to do this without having to directly adjust the timespec value yourself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, you need to ***normalize*** a `timespec` structure properly after you add an interval to `tv_nsec`.

One thing you can do is:

```
ts.tv_nsec += 20000000;
ts.tv_sec += ts.tv_nsec / 1000000000;
ts.tv_nsec %= 1000000000;
```

In Linux kernel, you can use `set_normalized_timespec()` to perform the normalization for you. Refer to [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time.c#L358).

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that your workaround is errant: You want to wait for 20 milliseconds, and yet in the instance where the nanosecond count is too big, you add 60 seconds: `ts.tv_sec += 60;`

Your workaround ought to look something like this:

```
ts.tv_nsec+=20000000;
if (ts.tv_nsec>=1000000000) {
    ts.tv_sec+=1;
    ts.tv_nsec-=1000000000;
}
```