# How to correctly use sem_timedwait()

Tags: c, time, pthreads, semaphore

i am trying to get my thread in my program to stop if it can't decrease the semaphore after 10 seconds (another thread could or could not increase it)
I saw that i could use sem_timedwait() for this but i cannot find a good example on the net.
So i just want to replace this:

```
sem_wait(&full);
//go on with stuff
```

with something like this:

```
sem_timedwait(&full,someTimeStuffThatRepresents10Secs);
if(sem_timedwaitTookLongerThan10){
    pthread.exit(NULL);
}else{
    //do stuff
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly set timespec for sem\_timedwait to protect against EINVAL error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254392/how-to-properly-set-timespec-for-sem-timedwait-to-protect-against-einval-error)

Answer (score 4):

```
/* Calculate relative interval as current time plus 10 seconds */

struct timespec ts;
if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts) == -1)
{
    /* handle error */
    return -1;
}

ts.tv_sec += 10;
while ((s = sem_timedwait(&full, &ts)) == -1 && errno == EINTR)
               continue;       /* Restart if interrupted by handler */
/* Check what happened */
if (s == -1)
{
    if (errno == ETIMEDOUT)
        printf("sem_timedwait() timed out\n");
    else
        perror("sem_timedwait");
} else
        printf("sem_timedwait() succeeded\n");
```

Linux Programmer's Manual gives thorough example on this at

> SEM_WAIT(3)

Please type `man sem_timedwait`  in console or visit documentation [online](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_timedwait).